# Replace variable names with actual class Properties - Regex? (C#)

Tags: regex, variables, replace, format

I need to send a custom email message to every User of a list ( List < User > ) I have. (I'm using C# .NET)
What I would need to do is to replace all the expressions (that start with "[?&=" have "variableName" in the middle and then ends with "]") with the actual User property value.

So for example if I have a text like this:

```
    "Hello, [?&=Name]. A gift will be sent to [?&=Address], [?&=Zipcode], [?&=Country]. 
If [?&=Email] is not your email address, please contact us."
```

I would like to get this for the user:

```
    "Hello, Mary. A gift will be sent to Boulevard Spain 918, 11300, Uruguay. 
If marytech@gmail.com is not your email address, please contact us."
```

Is there a practical and clean way to do this with Regex?

Comment: aplication javascript, php or other language ?

Comment: @Scaffold My bad, I didn't specify (I edited the question). I'm using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to apply regex.

The regular expression you want looks like this `/\[\?&=(\w*)\]/` [example](https://regex101.com/r/8HxUph/1)

You will need to do a replace on the input string using a method that allows you to use a custom function for replacement values. Then inside that function use the first capture value as the `Key` so to say and pull the correct corresponding value.

Since you did not specify what language you are using I will be nice and give you an example in C# and JS that I made for my own projects just recently.

Pseudo-Code

```
Loop through matches
Key is in first capture group
Check if replacements dict/obj/db/... has value for the Key
   if Yes, return Value
   else return ""
```

C#

```
email = Regex.Replace(email, @"\[\?&=(\w*)\]",
                match => //match contains a Key & Replacements dict has value for that key
                    match?.Groups[1].Value != null 
                    && replacements.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value)
                        ? replacements[match.Groups[1].Value]
                        : "");
```

JS

```
var content = text.replace(/\[\?&=(\w*)\]/g,
        function (match, p1) {

            return replacements[p1] || "";

        });
```